# too many arguments for method mapping: (apply: (String, String, String) => R)(unapply: R => Option[(String, String, String)])play.api.data.Mapping[R]

Tags: scala, play2-mini

```
val computerForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[Long]),
        "name" -> nonEmptyText,
        "introduced" -> optional(date("yyyy-MM-dd")),
        "discontinued" -> optional(date("yyyy-MM-dd")),
        "company" -> optional(longNumber)
    )(Computer.apply)(Computer.unapply)
)
```

this code giving me the error too many arguments for method mapping:

```
(apply: (String, String, String) => R)(unapply: R => Option[(String, String, String)])play.api.data.Mapping[R]..please solve this issue"
```

Comment: Can we see the definition of `Computer`, please?

Comment: Is Computer case class with five properties?

Comment: How would you get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go in order, from Play2 Scaladoc. The Form method you are calling is `Form.apply`

[Form scaladoc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form%24)

```
def apply[T](mapping: (String, Mapping[T])): Form[T]
```

so your mapping(smth) should return a `(String,Mapping[T])`. The mapping method is instead defined in the object `Forms`

[Forms Scaladoc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms%24%20/)

Forms.mapping is an overloaded method with multiple available signatures, let's look at one

```
def
mapping[R, A1, A2, A3, A4](a1: (String, Mapping[A1]), a2: (String, Mapping[A2]), a3: (String, Mapping[A3]), a4: (String, Mapping[A4]))(apply: (A1, A2, A3, A4) ⇒ R)(unapply: (R) ⇒ Option[(A1, A2, A3, A4)]): Mapping[R]
```

So this method takes a first list of parameters `(a1,a2,a3,a4)` each of type `(String,Mapping[Aindex])`, one another list of parameter containing a single parameter `apply: (A1, A2, A3, A4) ⇒ R` , and a last parameter list containing a single parameter `unapply: (R) ⇒ Option[(A1, A2, A3, A4)]`

In general, for all overloaded version of mapping, the signature impose  such that apply / unapply should have the signature corresponding a **tupled** version of the first list of parameter.

What is happening here, is that through `->` you are creating **5** `(String,Mappings[Asomething])` tuples, while your `apply/unapply` has only **3** arguments